# Why does the CPLEX Refiner not detect broken variable bounds?

Tags: cplex

Cplex (12.6 or 12.8) does not detect infeasable variable bounds when using the GetConflict or

I ran the code from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429472

IBM's example takes all original constraints of the problem and adds all variable bounds as additional constraints.

I have used this lp model for the test

```
Maximize
obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3
Subject To
c1: x2 + x3 <= 20
c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
c3: x1<= 20
c4: x1>=40
Bounds
40 <= x1 <= 00
Generals
x1 x2 x3
End
```

Note: the bounds of x1 are broken intentionally.

Using this edited lp file, i'd expect CPLEX to return the broken bounds as members of the infeasability set. But it doesn't. Just all constraints and bounds are excluded from the conflict set

[The IRange model including the variable bounds as constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeRot.png)

[The conflict refinement result: none of these constraints are in coflict (wrong!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ4sL.png)

[The cplex console output: correctly finds x1 is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3mv.png)

How to fix this? I'd like to get all the broken constraints in the result set.

Comment: I've reproduced your results. There does appear to be something wrong here. I'll take a closer look and then report back.

Comment: By the way, when asking a question in the future, please try to [avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It's much easier to for people to help you when you provide text because it can be easily copied, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [RefineConflict](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refdotnetcplex/html/M_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_RefineConflict.htm) method states:

> To check whether the bounds of a variable cause a conflict, use
>   instances of the class ILOG.Concert.INumVarBound to specify the upper
>   and lower bounds of the variable in question. Use those bounds like
>   constraints among the arguments you pass to refineConflict.

With that in mind, and using the technote as a starting point, try using the following block of code instead:

```
//add variable bounds to the constraints array
for(int c1=0;c1<lp.NumVars.Length;c1++)
{
    if (lp.GetNumVar(c1).Type != NumVarType.Bool)
    {
        // Instead of the following:
        // constraints[rng.Length + 2*numVarCounter] = cplex.AddLe(lp.GetNumVar(c1).LB, lp.GetNumVar(c1));
        // constraints[rng.Length + 2 * numVarCounter].Name = lp.GetNumVar(c1).ToString() + "_LB";
        // constraints[rng.Length + 2*numVarCounter + 1] = cplex.AddGe(lp.GetNumVar(c1).UB, lp.GetNumVar(c1));
        // constraints[rng.Length + 2 * numVarCounter + 1].Name = lp.GetNumVar(c1).ToString() + "_UB";
        // Use this:
        constraints[rng.Length + 2 * numVarCounter] = cplex.Bound(lp.GetNumVar(c1), NumVarBoundType.Lower);
        constraints[rng.Length + 2 * numVarCounter + 1] = cplex.Bound(lp.GetNumVar(c1), NumVarBoundType.Upper);
        numVarCounter++;
    }
}
```

With those changes, I get the following output:

```
Warning:  Bound infeasibility column 'x1'.
Solution status = Infeasible
Model Infeasible, Calling CONFLICT REFINER
Number of SOSs=0
Conflict Refinement process finished: Printing Conflicts
 Proved : IloRange c3 : -infinity <= (1*x1) <= 20
 Proved : IloRange c4 : 40 <= (1*x1) <= infinity
Conflict Summary:
 Constraint conflicts = 2
 Variable Bound conflicts = 0
 SOS conflicts = 0
Calling FEASOPT
Warning:  Bound infeasibility column 'x1'.
FeasOpt failed- Could not repair infeasibilities
```

Comment: Hi, 

that does the trick. amazing. the replaced lines have been taken from the cplex documentation.

Comment: Glad it's working for you now. I will pass this on to the folks in charge of the documentation so that this gets fixed.